# Как и зачем Class::app()->user->getData

Tags: php, ооп

Зачем реализовывать такой вызов методов Class::app()->user->getData и как это сделать. Спрашиваю ибо во многих фреймворках такая реализация.

Comment: потому, что у app может быть не только user, а и что то другое (может там page, section). А у user кроме данных (getData) может быть ещё и имя (допустим, это метод getName).

Видимо Вы слишком привыкли к php и ожидаете просто функции вида

    app_user_data();

Но для любого более-менее сложного проекта можно умориться генерировать имена.

Comment: Метод app должен возвращать обьект класса в свойстве user, а user, в свою очередь, обьект со свойством getData, так ведь? Но зачем я не могу понять? В чем приемущество и почему не лучше вызвать тот же app_user_data()?

Comment: @sargss в изоляции элементов друг от друга и построении гармоничной иерархии компонентов. Глобальные функции будут засорять общую область видимости и мешаться в том же автодополнении в IDE.

Comment: все очень просто - можно написать класс user и не переживать о том, где именно он будет использоваться. Его можно протестить и выверить.

Класс app не обязан знать о внутренностях user.

если app захочет создать массив user, то ему не нужно думать о том, какие данные также нужно в массив запихнуть.

Comment: Такой функционал реализовываеться в виде какого-то патерна? Я бы хотел на практике проверить такой подход.

Comment: видимо Ваш паттерн - разделяй и властвуй.

Comment: А серьезно? Интересно ведь.

Comment: @sargss, почитайте про SOLID. Конкретно нет никаких принципов-паттернов, как именно делить ответственность и распределять классы, есть принципы, которые влияют на это косвенно или по крайней мере не совсем напрямую. Я лично сейчас больше всего смотрю на легкость изолирования класса, могу ли я его выдернуть, набить изнутри моками (псевдозависимостями) и прогнать тесты.

Comment: это серьезно. Паттерны - это хорошо, пока не начался "паттерн головного мозга", когда их пихают везде.

В общем случае - каждый класс должен делать одну задачу и делать ее хорошо. Если какой то класс начинает делать много различных задач - пора его разделить на несколько классов.

А вот как разделять - это уже подскажут паттерны. Но для каждого случая нужно его подбирать.

Но я думаю, что не нужно прямо здесь пересказывать все паттерны. Приведите пример задачи - придумаем как разложить на классы.

Comment: @KoVadim, я не особо увлекаюсь паттернами, диагноз "паттерн головного мозга" мне не грозит.
@Etki, я знаком с ооп и его принципами, я бы хотел написать(скопипастить если есть откуда) код для создания обращений вида Class::app()->user->getData для изучения и использования

Comment: @sargss, SOLID - это совсем не "принципы ООП", про которые пишут в толстых хрустящих книжках, продающихся в Буквоеде. SOLID опирается на то, что предполагаемый код будет целиком состоять из объектов, но все-таки эта пятерка принципов немного о другом.

Сама цепочка `Class::app()->user->getData` поддерживается языком "из коробки", достаточно реализовать статический метод `app()`, который будет возвращать объект, в котором будет свойство user (опять-таки объект), у которого будет свойство (или метод?) getData.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это - паттерн [Singleton](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_%28%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%29#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.B5.D1.80_.D0.BD.D0.B0_PHP_5).

Используется для сущностей, которые в проекте существуют лишь в единственном экземпляре. Я допустим использую для текущего пользователя:

```
CurrentUser::instance()->getName();
```

Как это реализовать посмотрите в примере там же, на Wiki. Грубо говоря в статическом методе instance() вы один раз записываете объект в статическую переменную при первом вызове, при остальных вызовах вы просто получаете этот объект. И потом используете повсюду, где требуется.

Comment: А причем тут синглтон ? прочитайте вопрос лучше внимательно.